# Problemas con hilos en Java

Tags: java, hilos

El problema es el siguiente: se debe simular una taquilla de cine, en la que hay "n" cajas y llegan "m" clientes, estoy trabajando esto con hilos para saber cuando una de las cajas está ocupada, considerando las siguientes clases:

```
public class cliente {
    public String nombre;
    public int numeroBoletos;
    public boolean atendiendo = false;

    public cliente(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.numeroBoletos = (int)(Math.random() * ((10 - 1) + 1)) + 1;
    }

    public void setAntendiendo(boolean antendiendo) {
        this.atendiendo = antendiendo;
    }
}
```

Para el caso de la cajera en cuestion, hay que tener un contador pues al final se debe conocer el numero de clientes que ésta atendió.

```
public class cajera extends Thread {

    public Semaphore semaforo;
    public String nombre;
    public cliente cliente;
    public boolean ocupado = false;
    public int contador = 0;

    public cajera(Semaphore semaforo, String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.semaforo = semaforo;
    }

    public void setCliente(cliente cliente){
        this.cliente = cliente;
        this.ocupado = true;
    }

    public void quitCliente(){
        this.cliente = null;
        this.ocupado = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int espera = 0;
        try {
            this.semaforo.acquire();

            System.out.println(this.nombre + " recibe a " + this.cliente.nombre);
            int cobro = this.cliente.numeroBoletos * 15;
            System.out.println("cobra " + cobro);

            int min = 1, max = 5;
            espera = (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min;
            sleep(espera * 1000);
            contador++;
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            System.out.println(this.nombre + " termina de atender a " + this.cliente.nombre + " despues de " + espera + " segundos.\n");

            semaforo.release();
            quitCliente();
        }
    }
}
```

Consideremos la siguiente clase principal:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Semaphore semaforo = new Semaphore(1);

        ArrayList<cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<cajera> cajeras = new ArrayList<>();

        int numeroClientes = 2, numeroCajeras = 1;

        //creacion de clientes
        for (int i = 0; i < numeroClientes; i++) {
            cliente c = new cliente("cliente " + (i + 1));
            clientes.add(c);
        }

        //creacion de cajeras
        for (int i = 0; i < numeroCajeras; i++) {
            cajera c = new cajera(semaforo, "cajera " + (i + 1));
            cajeras.add(c);
        }
        /************************************************/
        do{
            //asignacion de clientes
            for (int i = 0; i < clientes.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < cajeras.size(); j++) {
                    if (cajeras.get(j).ocupado == false && clientes.get(i).atendiendo == false) {
                        cajeras.get(j).setCliente(clientes.get(i));

                        cajeras.get(j).ocupado = true;
                        clientes.get(i).atendiendo = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < cajeras.size(); i++) {
                if ((cajeras.get(i).ocupado == true)) {
                    cajeras.get(i).start();
                    cajeras.get(i).join();
                }
            }

            //removemos a los clientes ya atendidos
            for (int i = 0; i < clientes.size(); i++) {
                if (clientes.get(i).atendiendo == true) {
                    clientes.remove(i);
                }
            }

            //liberamos a las cajeras para el nuevo ciclo
            for(int i = 0; i < cajeras.size(); i++){
                cajeras.get(i).ocupado = false;
            }
        }while(clientes.size() != 0);
        /*************************************************/

        for (int i = 0; i < cajeras.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(cajeras.get(i).nombre + " atendió a " + cajeras.get(i).contador + " clientes");
        }
    }
```

Ahora, la ventana resultante en la salida es la siguiente:

```
cajera 1 recibe a cliente 1
cobra 90
cajera 1 termina de atender a cliente 1 despues de 4 segundos.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:795)
    at Practica4.test.main(test.java:52)
```

La cuestión aquí es que, cuando hay más clientes que cajas, se entra a un ciclo que toma como consideración el hecho de que, cada que se atiende a un cliente, se elimina de la lista de clientes, naturalmente se debe verificar que mientras no sea 0 la longitud de la lista de clientes, es porque aún hay clientes, por ende, sigue el ciclo. Veo aquí que el valor del hilo no es cero, esto por la siguiente condicion en *java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:795)*:

```
if (threadStatus != 0)
            throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿Es posible reiniciar el hilo o setear el valor en cero al terminar de usarlo? ¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?

Comment: No se puede reiniciar un hilo, debes crear otra instancia de `Cajera` para poder iniciarla. La manera en que lo estás haciendo con contadores y demás puede introducir inconsistencias por condiciones de carrera. Te recomiendo usar un `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` en lugar de un `ArrayList` para almacenar a los clientes y que se lo inyectes a cada `Cajera` para que dentro de un ciclo vayan sacando `Cliente` por `Cliente` hasta que no quede ninguno.

Comment: Modifiqué la clase principal considerando las ConcurrentLinkedQueue, y ayudó bastante, además de simplificarlo, muchas gracias :)